# Facing my stickman in the correct way JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I’m making an educational online board game and I have made I stickman as the main character. I use arrow keys for the user to guide him along the board.
I am trying to make him face the way he’s going but I’ve only managed to make his eyes and mouth face the opposite way. His arms keep swaying forward in odd manners that change every time I hit the arrow key.
I was wonder If anybody could spot my error. I have surfed the internet and rewritten the code in many ways to no avail. Here is the important code:

```js
window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  switch (e.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
      update();
      icon.style.left = parseInt(icon.style.left) - moveBy + "px";
      eye.style.right = 65 + "%";
      mouth.style.right = 40 + "%";
      arm1.style.animation = "walk-arm2 1s infinite";
      arm_after1.style.animation =  " walk-arm-after2 1s infinite";
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      update();
      icon.style.left = parseInt(icon.style.left) + moveBy + "px";
      eye.style.right = 25 + "%";
      mouth.style.right = 0 + "%";
      arm1.style.animation = " walk-arm 1s infinite";
      arm_after1.style.animation = "walk-arm-after 1s infinite";
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      update();
      icon.style.top = parseInt(icon.style.top) - moveBy + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      update();
      icon.style.top = parseInt(icon.style.top) + moveBy + "px";
  }
  verifyThePosition();
  verifyThePosition2();
  verifyThePosition3();
  verifyThePosition4();
  // verifyThePosition2(targetButton);
});

function openShop() {
  // shopWindow.classList.add('show');
}
// shopBtn.addEventListener('click', )
function verifyThePosition() {
  // console.log(icon.style.left, icon.style.top)
  if (icon.style.left == "650px" && icon.style.top == "50px") {
    let selectedModal = "modal";
    rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 45) + 1;
    console.log(rn);
    document.querySelector("#modal" + rn).classList.add("show");
  }
}

function verifyThePosition2() {
  // console.log(icon.style.left, icon.style.top) 
  if (icon.style.left == "375px" && icon.style.top == "325px") {
    let selectedModal = "modal";
    rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 45) + 1;
    console.log(rn);
    document.querySelector("#modal" + rn).classList.add("show");
  }
}

function verifyThePosition3() {
  // console.log(icon.style.left, icon.style.top)
  if (icon.style.left == "700px" && icon.style.top == "600px") {
    let selectedModal = "modal";
    rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 45) + 1;
    console.log(rn);
    document.querySelector("#modal" + rn).classList.add("show");
  }
}

function verifyThePosition4() {
  // console.log(icon.style.left, icon.style.top)
  if (icon.style.left == "875px" && icon.style.top == "75px") {
    let selectedModal = "modal";
    rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 45) + 1;
    console.log(rn);
    document.querySelector("#modal" + rn).classList.add("show");
  }
}
```

```css
.stickman {
  transition: 300ms ease-in;
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 50%;
  left: 50%; */
  margin-top: -10em;
  margin-left: -5em;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid;
  animation: 0.5s walk-body ease-in infinite;
  z-index: 10;
}
.stickman .head {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 25%;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.stickman .head .eye {
  height: 0.225em;
  width: 0.225em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32.5%;
  right: 25%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.stickman .head .mouth {
  height: 0.1125em;
  width: 1.2285714286em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(11.25deg);
  background-color: #fff;
}
.stickman .body {
  height: 3.6666666667em;
  width: 0.325em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5em;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -0.3125em;
  background-color: #111;
}
.stickman .body .arm {
  height: 2em;
  width: 0.325em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top;
  background: #111;
  animation: 1s walk-arm infinite;
}
.stickman .body .arm#left {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  background: #222;
}
.stickman .body .arm#left::after {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  background: #222;
}
.stickman .body .arm::after {
  content: "";
  height: 1.3333333333em;
  width: 0.325em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  background: #111;
  animation: 1s walk-arm-after infinite;
}
.stickman .body .leg {
  height: 4.1666666667em;
  width: 0.325em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4.1666666667em;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top;
  background: #222;
  animation: 1s walk-leg infinite;
}
.stickman .body .leg#right {
  background: #111;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes walk-body {
  0% {
    margin-top: -11.25em;
    padding-bottom: 1.25em;
  }
  50% {
    margin-top: -10em;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: -11.25em;
    padding-bottom: 1.25em;
  }
}
@keyframes walk-arm {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes walk-arm-after {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(67.5deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(67.5deg);
  }
}
@keyframes walk-arm2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes walk-arm-after2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-67.5deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-67.5deg);
  }
}
@keyframes walk-leg {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='stickman'>
    <div class='head'>
      <div class='eye'></div>
      <div class='mouth'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='body'>
      <div class='arm' id='left'></div>
      <div class='arm' id='right'></div>
      <div class='leg' id='left'></div>
      <div class='leg' id='right'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thank you before ward,
Dimitri

Comment: Do you want to show him like this? https://nimb.ws/tYR7TW

Comment: Hi, could you make your code into a full working snippet - at the moment some functions and the definition of icon are missing and as you have the positioning 50%,50% commented out we only see part of one leg not the full man.

Comment: @mfn0 that is what the man looks like